# How to make nullable a relationship ManytoOne

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have one relationship ManyToOne between two entities:Usuario and Departamento,Some users dont have any departaments,i want to make nullable the field departamento in the entity Usuario,how to make this.My code looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace CECMED\TarifaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Usuario
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CECMED\TarifaBundle\Entity\UsuarioRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
  */
class Usuario implements UserInterface{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="No debe dejar este campo vacío")
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string",unique=true, length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="No debe dejar este campo vacío")
     * @ORM\Column(name="apellidos", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $apellidos;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="No debe dejar este campo vacío")
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Departamento", inversedBy="usuarios")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_departamento", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $departamento;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Departamento", inversedBy="usuarios")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_departamento", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $departamento;
```

As shown above you should put the attribute `nullable` onto `JoinColumn`

### Don't forget

to update your schema `doctrine:schema:update --force`

Moreover if you had already generated your setters, remember to change it in order to accept nullable values, like this  `setDepartamento(Departamento $departamento = null)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `nullable=true` instead of `false`?

Comment: @dragoste, yes, I had a typo

Comment: i add nullable=true en my relationship and when i insert an user this is the error:

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT d0_.id AS id0, d0_.nombre AS nombre1, d0_.id_dependencia AS id_dependencia2 FROM departamento d0_ WHERE d0_.id IN (?)' with params [""]:

SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «»

Comment: @JesúsSotoMitjans: you should update your schema with proper command or generate migrations (if you use it)